How accurate is the testing MOSFET in circuit using multimeter?
how accurate is the testing MOSFET in circuit using multimeter ?
can a defective mosfet give good results, because it is still soldered?

In general, it's very difficult to test a FET in-circuit.  Gate driver circuitry will prevent a good read on the integrity of the gate (looking at gate resistance/capacitance).
Loads connected to the drain may interfere with checking the body diode. If you measure a dead-short drain to source that MIGHT give you a hint that there's a problem.
If it's an application where you can power the circuit and statically measure the voltage across the FET when it's on under load, and again when it's off, you should be able to determine if it's working, but that's a corner case.
So in general you have to remove the FET to get a meaningful result.

You may be able to detect a defective MOSFET (for example, shorted) with an ohmmeter if you know (and understand) what is connected  to the MOSFET and  if you understand how that circuitry behaves with no power. You also may be able to detect it with your nose or visually.
But that does not cover all possible faults, and it requires specific knowledge and skills.

This is a totally different question and should be presented as one. The answer will depend on the circuit, in general, so more information will be more likely to lead to a useful question, less information is more likely to lead to the question being quickly closed.
